# How can I check in chai an array + type?

Tags: graphql, chai

```
const userOverviewType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'dayOverviewData',
    fields: () => ({
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(user),
        },
    }),
});
```

I want test this object type in chai. My test is:

```
expect(userOverviewType.getFields().users.type).to.deep.equals([ user ]);
```

the test fail:

```
1) User userOverviewType Should have a days field of type GraphQLList:
         AssertionError: expected [user] to deeply equal [ user ]
          at Assertion.assertEqual (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:485:19)
          at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as equals] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)
          at Context.<anonymous> (src/test/station.server.spec.js:133:65)
```

How is the correct code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of chai test was wrong. The correct test is:

```
expect(userOverviewType.getFields().users.type).to.be.an.instanceof(graphql.GraphQLList);   
expect(graphql.getNamedType(userOverviewType.getFields().users.type)).to.deep.equals(userData.user);
```